# How to place all soft math functions to separate section

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded, ld

i'm developing software for arm Cortex M1 microcontroller without FPU. I want to try to place all of the soft math functions to separate section and place it into internal RAM to increase speed. I'm trying to do it using ldscript

```
.fast_text :
{
*.text(*__aeabi_*)
. = ALIGN(4);
} > INTRAM
```

but unfortunately in map file i see that fast_text section is empty.

Comment: You cannot directly put the code into a RAM section. You must store it into flash and copy it to RAM at power up/startup. Otherwise how do you expect the code magically appare in RAM, where all data are lost at power down?...

Comment: that's okay. I've got a bootloader which can read elf file stored in EEPROM. After power up it can read elf and place .text section and. data section into external RAM. And i want to create a new section .fast_text to place it into internal RAM

Comment: yes it is. I'm using cortex-m1

Comment: I don't know about the linker, but you can simply compile the code as `PIC` and copy your code "manually" wherever you need and then jump to it.

Comment: i need to copy only exact fuctions, because i have 4 Mb of external static RAM and only 32KB of internal RAM. I need to copy exact fuctions which names starts with __aeabi_*

Comment: So edit your question with all those info.

Comment: @dwelch At the time of comment, it was an unknown arm-m6 ;)

Comment: Are all of your functions in the same source file?  you can use sourcename.o in the linker script to put the whole source file somewhere.

Comment: i've found solution

.fasttext
{
*(.text)
}>INTRAM
.text
{
*(.text*)
}

Comment: No it is a mcu 1986ve1t